# der Wand oder die Wand

Tags: english-to-german, article, standard-german

(Die Wand)

An der wand hängen Bilder. (Menschen A2.1 Buch)

Das Bild an die Wand hängen. (Dictionary)

We need to use Dative because we want to know the location of the Bild oder Bilder but in the dictionary, they use Akkusativ.

Comment: Note that in the first example “Bilder” is the subject, in the second “das Bild” is an Akkusativ object.

Comment: and your question is what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking this will be closed because it's basically an application of the rule for *Wechselpräpositionen*, and there's a link to a question which explains that. In this case, first example describes what a picture is doing; it's just hanging there in the same place, so the dative is called for. The second example describes what a person is doing with the picture, they are moving it to a new location and so the accusative is called for. It helps if you look at the entire sentence for context since many times you can only tell which case to use when you understand exactly what is happening.